# Angular app container is not accessible from browser

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile

Trying to dockerize angular application from docker file

docker file

```
FROM node:12.2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@6.0.8
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 4200
CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

the image builds successfully

[image]

then `docker run test:latest` and it compiles successfully. The issue now is that `http://localhost:4200/` isn’t working, in other words, the app not showing up in the browser.

Comment: Try with `docker run -p 4200:4200  test:latest`

Comment: I have done like this `docker run -p 4200:4201 test:latest` but was not accessible, just wondering  why it works when append the same port ?

Comment: Does it because the command `EXPOSE 4200` in docker file?

Comment: The pattern for port mapping is `HOST:CONTAINER`. On container angular app is running on 4200 not 4201. With `-p 4200:4201` you are mapping container's port 4201(no service running there) to host's port 4200. `EXPOSE` instruction is more like a documentation feature, informing others that your image's service runs on specified port.

Comment: Note: comments are to explain things, not just rewrite the code in English. The comments you have here are worse than bad -- they take time to maintain yet add no value whatsoever. You can't argue that they are for a non-technical reader to uderstand the dockerfile, because nobody who doesn't understand dockerfiles would be working with this code, and if they were there would be better ways to learn what's going on than these comments. I have removed them from the question because they hinder the readability of the code.

Comment: Also, you should use entrypoint 'exec' rather than cmd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to forward the port from the container to your system / host :

```
docker run -p 4200:4200 test:latest
```